# Calling a stored procedure from a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to call a stored procedure from  a select statement but it isn't working.

Anyone have an idea?

This is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [eversuite_localization].[Resource_GetAll] 
AS 
BEGIN       
    SELECT [ResourceId],
           [ResourceKey], 
           EXECUTE  ([eversuite_localization].[Resource_GetResourceValue] ResourceID) ,
           [CultureId],[ClassId],[ResourceType]     
    FROM   [eversuite_localization].[Resource]   
END
```

Comment: What does the stored procedure do? If you want "eversuite_localization" to return a value that should display a column, make it a function.

Comment: The stored procedure selects a value from a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to do that

You will have to insert it into a temp/variable table first.

Have a look at  [Insert Values of Stored Procedure in Table – Use Table Valued Function](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/23/sql-server-insert-values-of-stored-procedure-in-table-use-table-valued-function/)

An alternative is using APPLY and functions

[Using APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx)

> The APPLY operator allows you to
>   invoke a table-valued function for
>   each row returned by an outer table
>   expression of a query.

**EDIT**

from your comment

> The stored procedure selects a value
>   from a table

Rather use a [scalar function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I want the stored procedure to select a value wich type is NTEXT.

Comment: I tried creating a function but i can't return an NTEXT value

Comment: SQL prevented me from returning a variable wich type is NTEXT

Comment: OK< have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx *ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of MicrosoftSQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.*